# Paperclip s3 storage not working with aws-sdk gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, paperclip

I'm trying to use the paperclip gem to upload photos in my rails project.

I my gem file:

```
gem "paperclip", "~> 2.4"
gem "aws-sdk"
```

On my model:

```
has_attached_file :image,
    :styles => { :large => "600x600>", :standard => "450x450>", :medium => "300x300>", :medium_square => "310x310#", :small => "200x200>", :thumb => "150x150>", :small_square => "50x50#" },
    :storage => :s3,
    :s3_credentials => "#{Rails.root}/config/aws.yml",
    :path => ":id/:hash/:style.:extension",
    :hash_secret => ''
```

But I keep getting an unitiliazed constant error on AWS::Base? I can't see what's wrong.

Comment: Use native s3 communication using aws-sdk : http://www.loudthinking.org/2012/10/rails-how-to-use-aws-sdk-for-native-s3.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The docs are currently wrong. You're reading the master doc, which does tell you to pull `~2.4` and use `aws-sdk`, but that `~2.4` line actually pulls a version of the gem which is actually different than the branch whose docs you're reading, and that version still uses the old s3 gem.

Change your gemfile to this:

`gem 'paperclip', :git => 'git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git'`

And then the aws-sdk gem should work.

Comment: Thank you! God that took me hours. I'll report back if it solves my problem.

Comment: Yeah, wasted hours of my time trying to figure it out, too.